# Given that A and B are sets such that A ⊆ B, write down P(A) − P(B) in a simplified form

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The question is: Given that A and B are sets such that A ⊆ B, write down P(A) − P(B) in a simplified form

I'm not sure what they mean by simplified form

Comment: There is nothing in the question that specify that $A$ and $B$ are *finite*.

Comment: If $A \subseteq B$, then every subset of $A$ is a subset of $B$.

Comment: Thus, in $\mathcal P(A) \setminus \mathcal P(B)$ we have to "remove" from $\mathcal P(A)$ all elements that are subsets of $B$.

Comment: You're giving the number of elements of $P(A)-P(B)$, which is not what the question asked. What set is $P(A)-P(B)$?

Comment: I don't really get this question. I don't think there's a way to write this set in fewer symbols than $P(A) - P(B)$.

Comment: @hunter me neither but this is what was asked

Comment: oh I get it -- the names of $A$ and $B$ are turned around. $A$ is the smaller set but you're supposed to simplify $P(A) - P(B)$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given: $A \subseteq B$.

$C \in \mathscr{P}(A)$ implies $C \subseteq A$ so $C \subseteq B$, so $C \in \mathscr{P}(B)$. Conclusion : $\mathscr{P}(A) \subseteq \mathscr{P}(B)$.

$\mathscr{P}(B) \setminus \mathscr{P}(A) = \emptyset$ is quite simplified...

Comment: Oh, I get it now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

This has nothing to do with $A$ and $B$ being finite or not.

What can you say of a subset $X$ of $A$ which is not in $\mathscr{P}(B)$?

Comment: This is a strange question. What answer do you have in mind?

Comment: Extra Hint: remember that $A\subseteq B$.

Comment: Does it mean that for a subset X of A which is not in P(B) is P(A) - P(B)? Is that the answer?

Comment: No, that would be a tautology. The answer is $P(\text{something})$.